# limiting the width of text box

Tags: jquery, html, css

I encountered a problem where the contents of a `<p>` or a `<div>` can have a long text string without spaces. What I want to do is limit the width of the `<p>` or `<div>` so that when the text is wider than the width, it doesn't force the width to be wider than what I specified.  I tried every style I could think of to limit the width but nothing has worked so far.

```html
<div style='100px;'>
  <p style="width: 100px;">
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting.  I was going to tell you to use the `max-width` property and link you [**here**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dim_max-width) but when I entered text with a long string without spaces it ignored the `max-width` property.

Comment: Look at overflow-wrap: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly I thought all you would need was the `max-width` property, but it gets ignored if you have a text string without spaces that's wider than the the `max-width` specified.  So in order to accomplish what you need, you also have to have `word-wrap: break-word;`.  This combination will work.

```css
p {
        max-width: 100px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit.
  </p>

  <p>
    HereIsAnotherParagraphWithALongTextStringWithoutAnySpacesAndSeeHowItWordWrapsWithoutWideningTheParagraph.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: thats a really big help

Comment: @GodwinRomero  If this works for you then please mark as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try property **word-wrap: break-word;** and even **white-space: pre-wrap;** for better use.